# Pentaho Analzyer - Mondrian Performance with large Date sets

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence, analyzer, mondrian, large-data

I am facing some performance issues in Pentaho. It is very slow.
the data set size is around 3,500,000 rows

Does anyone have the same problem? I am not sure if it is because of Pentaho Analyzer or Mondrian

Did anyone experience Analyzer or Mondrian with large Data Sets? size ? how is the performance? is it really the suitable tool for such data set?
any advice plz?

thanks

Comment: Usually analyzer itself does not cause performance issues: rendering time should be quite small with respect to DB requests or mondrian aggregation time. Can you add more details? It would be nice to see at least query execution  timings? You can check analyzer logs to get information regarding sql execution time, mondrian execution time and rendering time. Depending on these timings, your use-cases and your environment, different optimization techniques may be employed.

Comment: @user4637357:Thanks for your answer. Here is the sql log:
SEGMENT.LOAD: DONE EXECUTING SQL[
SELECT 
"DIM_ES"."ES_ID" AS "c0"
,"DIM_ES_MAE"."ES_MA_NAME" AS "c1"
,SUM("DIM_ES"."count_ES") AS "m0"
FROM "DIM_ES" "DIM_ES","DIM_ES_MAE" "DIM_ES_MAE"
WHERE "DIM_ES"."ES_ID"="DIM_ES_MAE"."ES_ID"
AND "DIM_ES_MAE"."ES_MA_NAME" IN ('Here is a long list of elements>100')
GROUP BY "DIM_ES"."ES_ID","DIM_ES_MAE"."ES_MA_NAME"],
EXEC+ FETCH 58465 ms,829129 rows,ex=91,CLOSE=90, OPEN=[54]. Although its a simple query, but it took 58 seconds, Do you have any advice why this is happening? thanks

Comment: Are your mondrian server and your DB server located in same network? If not then I'd suspect that you are limited with network bandwidth here: first you need to transfer all the names (which are likely to be strings) for the `IN` clause of your query, then you need to transfer the names along with IDs and SUMs from DB to mondrian as query results.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to check the query execution plan directly in DB in order to check whether there are issues on DB side (e.g. bad statistics or lack of indexes).

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Mondrian fires off queries to the database in a ROLAP style- and although it gives value as a 'semantic layer' to make queries easier, it isn't always going to generate the best performing queries. If you want a technology that improves performance, it probably wouldn't be the right one for you.